# An associative Entity with optional participation on one side and mandatory participation on the other

Tags: many-to-many, relationship, entity-relationship, erd, conceptual-model

I get confused sometimes when trying to understand business rules and translating them into ERD using Crow's Foot Notation.

This is the Business Rule:

- Candidates can pay a fee to attend a training session. A training session can accommodate several candidates, although new training sessions will not have any candidates registered at first.

This is what I did:

[image: This is what I did]

My Questions:

- Is this correct?
- Should both sides of the associative entity be optional participation?
- When breaking "Many to Many" relationships, should the "one" side always have mandatory participation?
- If no participation is mentioned in the business rule, is the default participation "mandatory (1)" or "optional (0)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is correct, but:

- Your initial many-to-many says that a session can have several candidates but may have none, but that candidates mut have at least one session. Your second diagram says the same thing.
- Both diagrams require a candidate to have at least one session. So according to the diagram,  a candidate **must** attend a session.  But the narrative says "Candidates **can** pay a fee to attend a training session".  So according to the narrative,  it should be optional also.

When using an associative table,  the *one* side of the decomposition should have mandatory participation.  If it would not be mandatory, you could have rows in the associative table that corresponds to not have a conter-part and hence do not correspond to a valid relationship between the two associated entities.  Imagine for example that the student would receive a grade for each of the enrolments. If one side would be missing, the grade would then be completely irrelevant.